How to read, parse and output content from a csv file in jsPsych
I am writing a code for a behavioural cognitive science experiment.
I am using JsPsych 7.3.4 version.
I am trying to read a csv file, which has this format:
csv file
After reading (and parsing) the file, I need to present auditorily 399 chunks of 4 words pairs to each subject (corresponding to a subj_ID). Then, ask the user/subject to give 2 keyboard responses after each chunk of 4 pairs. The chunks are corresponding to the rows in the csv file, where the 'options' columns contain the item that constitute the word stimuli inside. Each word, since should be presented auditorily, is corresponding to an audio file inside the project folder, mapped by a mapping object.
Everything works in the browser console (the arrays are outputted as they should) but the audio are not played. Can you spot which is the issue?
Thank you so much! :)
This is the code (I've got some extra console.log to try to de-bug):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My experiment</title>
    <script src="js/dist/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dist/plugin-html-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dist/plugin-audio-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dist/plugin-html-button-response.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dist/plugin-call-function.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
    <link href="js/dist/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>

    var jsPsych = initJsPsych({
        use_webaudio: false,
        on_close: function() {},
        show_progress_bar: true,
    });

    var timeline = [];

    var start_button = {
        type: jsPsychHtmlButtonResponse,
        stimulus: "Clicchi il bottone qua sotto per iniziare l'esperimento",
        choices: ['Inizia'],
        data: { phase: 'start' },
    };
    timeline.push(start_button);

    var official_stimuli_mapping = [
        {word: 'piazza', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/piazza.mp3'},
        {word: 'colore', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/colore.mp3'},
        {word: 'pennello', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/pennello.mp3'},
        {word: 'albero', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/albero.mp3'},
        {word: 'vita', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/vita.mp3'},
        {word: 'erba', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/erba.mp3'},
        {word: 'sorella', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/sorella.mp3'},
        {word: 'quadro', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/quadro.mp3'},
        {word: 'persona', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/persona.mp3'},
        {word: 'teatro', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/teatro.mp3'},
        {word: 'poltrona', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/poltrona.mp3'},
        {word: 'pineta', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/pineta.mp3'},
        {word: 'castello', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/castello.mp3'},
        {word: 'bicchiere', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/bicchiere.mp3'},
        {word: 'birra', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/birra.mp3'},
        {word: 'treno', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/treno.mp3'},
        {word: 'macchina', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/macchina.mp3'},
        {word: 'verde', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/verde.mp3'},
        {word: 'speranza', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/speranza.mp3'},
        {word: 'nipote', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/nipote.mp3'},
        {word: 'temporale', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/temporale.mp3'},
        {word: 'acqua', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/acqua.mp3'},
        {word: 'bolla', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/bolla.mp3'},
        {word: 'foglia', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/foglia.mp3'},
        {word: 'maestro', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/maestro.mp3'},
        {word: 'scuola', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/scuola.mp3'},
        {word: 'arte', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/arte.mp3'},
        {word: 'tetto', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/tetto.mp3'},
        {word: 'aquila', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/aquila.mp3'},
        {word: 'chitarra', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/chitarra.mp3'},
        {word: 'azzurro', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/azzurro.mp3'},
        {word: 'bagno', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/bagno.mp3'},
        {word: 'occhiali', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/occhiali.mp3'},
        {word: 'cravatta', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/cravatta.mp3'},
        {word: 'guanto', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/guanto.mp3'},
        {word: 'campagna', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/campagna.mp3'},
        {word: 'agricoltura', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/agricoltura.mp3'},
        {word: 'montagna', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/montagna.mp3'},
        {word: 'orizzonte', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/orizzonte.mp3'},
        {word: 'ombra', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/ombra.mp3'},
        {word: 'tasca', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/tasca.mp3'},
        {word: 'pecora', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/pecora.mp3'},
        {word: 'maglione', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/maglione.mp3'},
        {word: 'valigia', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/valigia.mp3'},
        {word: 'grano', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/grano.mp3'},
        {word: 'rotella', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/rotella.mp3'},
        {word: 'zaino', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/zaino.mp3'},
        {word: 'elettrico', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/elettrico.mp3'},
        {word: 'computer', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/computer.mp3'},
        {word: 'irrigazione', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/irrigazione.mp3'},
        {word: 'vasca', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/vasca.mp3'},
        {word: 'fienile', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/fienile.mp3'},
        {word: 'sedile', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/sedile.mp3'},
        {word: 'nonno', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/nonno.mp3'},
        {word: 'cioccolato', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/cioccolato.mp3'},
        {word: 'corda', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/corda.mp3'},
        {word: 'contadina', audio: '../dynamic_script/audio/stimuli/contadina.mp3'},
    ];

    function readTextFile(file, subjectID, callback) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
        console.log("Emma");
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log("Emma2", rawFile);
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)) {
                var csvData = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log("Emma");
                console.log("DATA", csvData);
                var processedData = [];
                Papa.parse(csvData, {
                    header: true,
                    skipEmptyLines: true,
                    complete: function (results) {
                        console.log("Papa parsing complete");
                        console.log("DATA", csvData);
                        results.data.forEach(row => {
                            const currentSubjectID = row["Participant_ID"];
                            if (currentSubjectID === subjectID) {
                                var stimuliChunk = [];
                                const options = [
                                    row["option1"], row["option2"], row["option3"], row["option4"],
                                ];
                                console.log('options', options);
                                const flattenedOptions = options.flat();
                                for (let i = 0; i < flattenedOptions.length; i += 4) {
                                    if (i + 3 < flattenedOptions.length) {
                                        const pair1 = flattenedOptions[i].split(',').map(option => option.trim());
                                        const pair2 = flattenedOptions[i + 1].split(',').map(option => option.trim());
                                        const pair3 = flattenedOptions[i + 2].split(',').map(option => option.trim());
                                        const pair4 = flattenedOptions[i + 3].split(',').map(option => option.trim());
                                        if (pair1.length === 2 && pair2.length === 2 && pair3.length === 2 && pair4.length === 2) {
                                            stimuliChunk.push([
                                                [pair1[0], pair1[1]],
                                                [pair2[0], pair2[1]],
                                                [pair3[0], pair3[1]],
                                                [pair4[0], pair4[1]]
                                            ]);
                                        } else {
                                            console.log('Difficulty with pairs');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (stimuliChunk[0].length === 4) {
                                    processedData.push(stimuliChunk[0]);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('Not enough pairs for stimuliChunk');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        if (processedData.length > 0) {
                            console.log('Processed data ready');
                            callback(processedData);
                        } else if (stimuliChunk.length > 0) {
                            console.log('Watch out: some stimuli remained outside');
                        } else {
                            console.log('No processed data or stimuliChunk');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    function presentAndProcessStimuli(processedData) {
        // var stimuliTimeline = []
        processedData.forEach(stimuliChunk => {
            console.log('for each presented stimuli', processedData, stimuliChunk)
            // var stimuli_trials = [];
            stimuliChunk.forEach(pair => {
                // var pair_timeline = [];
                pair.forEach((word, index) => {
                    var mapping = official_stimuli_mapping.find(item => item.word === word);
                    // stimulus: official_stimuli_mapping.find(item => item.word === "bolla").audio,
                    if (mapping) {
                        console.log("Stimulus:", mapping.audio, 'word', word, 'index', index); // Check if audio stimulus path is correct
                        var word_presentation = {
                            type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                            stimulus: mapping.audio,
                            choices: "NO_KEYS",
                            trial_ends_after_audio: true,
                            post_trial_gap: index === 0 ? null : 900, // Longer gap after second word
                            on_finish: function (data) {
                                if (data.audio_playback_error) {
                                    console.error("Audio playback error:", data.audio_playback_error);}}
                            };
                        timeline.push(word_presentation)
                        console.log("Word presented:", word_presentation.stimulus);
                    } else {
                        console.error("Mapping not found for word:", word);
                    }
                });
                // stimuli_trials.push(pair_timeline);
            });

            var response = {
                timeline: [
                    {
                        type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                        stimulus: '../dynamic_script/audio/sounds/separation_sound.mp3',
                        choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                        response_ends_trial: true,
                        post_trial_gap: 900,
                        on_finish: function (data) {
                            if (data.audio_playback_error) {
                                console.error("Audio playback error:", data.audio_playback_error);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                        stimulus: '../dynamic_script/audio/sounds/separation_sound.mp3',
                        choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                        response_ends_trial: true,
                        post_trial_gap: 1000,
                        on_finish: function (data) {
                            if (data.audio_playback_error) {
                                console.error("Audio playback error:", data.audio_playback_error);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ]
            };
            console.log("RESPONSE:");
            timeline.push(response);
            // timeline_read.push(pair_timeline);
        });
        // timeline.push(stimuliTimeline);
        // Run the timeline_read after processing
    }

    readTextFile("../stimuli_selection/files/subjIDs_trials_dataframe.csv", "sbj_1", function(processedData) {
        presentAndProcessStimuli(processedData);
    });
    var example_two = {
        type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
        stimulus: official_stimuli_mapping.find(item => item.word === "bolla").audio,
        choices: "NO_KEYS",
        trial_ends_after_audio: true,
        post_trial_gap: 1000
    };

    timeline.push(example_two);
    jsPsych.run(timeline);
    console.log("Loaded timeline:", timeline);

    official_stimuli_mapping.forEach(item => {
        console.log("Stimulus:", item.audio);
    });
    // Run the main timeline


</script>
</html>
```


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried with some previous functions without the csv reading and that one was working. The function was as such:

    var official_stimuli_mapping = [
        {word: 'piazza', audio: 'audio/stimuli/piazza.mp3'},
        {word: 'colore', audio: 'audio/stimuli/colore.mp3'},
        {word: 'pennello', audio: 'audio/stimuli/pennello.mp3'},
        {word: 'albero', audio: 'audio/stimuli/albero.mp3'},
        {word: 'vita', audio: 'audio/stimuli/vita.mp3'},
        {word: 'erba', audio: 'audio/stimuli/erba.mp3'},
        {word: 'sorella', audio: 'audio/stimuli/sorella.mp3'},
        {word: 'quadro', audio: 'audio/stimuli/quadro.mp3'},
        {word: 'persona', audio: 'audio/stimuli/persona.mp3'},
        {word: 'teatro', audio: 'audio/stimuli/teatro.mp3'},
        {word: 'poltrona', audio: 'audio/stimuli/poltrona.mp3'},
        {word: 'pineta', audio: 'audio/stimuli/pineta.mp3'},
        {word: 'castello', audio: 'audio/stimuli/castello.mp3'},
        {word: 'bicchiere', audio: 'audio/stimuli/bicchiere.mp3'},
        {word: 'birra', audio: 'audio/stimuli/birra.mp3'},
        {word: 'treno', audio: 'audio/stimuli/treno.mp3'},
        {word: 'macchina', audio: 'audio/stimuli/macchina.mp3'},
        {word: 'verde', audio: 'audio/stimuli/verde.mp3'},
        {word: 'speranza', audio: 'audio/stimuli/speranza.mp3'},
        {word: 'nipote', audio: 'audio/stimuli/nipote.mp3'},
        {word: 'temporale', audio: 'audio/stimuli/temporale.mp3'},
        {word: 'acqua', audio: 'audio/stimuli/acqua.mp3'},
        {word: 'bolla', audio: 'audio/stimuli/bolla.mp3'},
        {word: 'foglia', audio: 'audio/stimuli/foglia.mp3'},
        {word: 'maestro', audio: 'audio/stimuli/maestro.mp3'},
        {word: 'scuola', audio: 'audio/stimuli/scuola.mp3'},
        {word: 'arte', audio: 'audio/stimuli/arte.mp3'},
        {word: 'tetto', audio: 'audio/stimuli/tetto.mp3'},
        {word: 'aquila', audio: 'audio/stimuli/aquila.mp3'},
        {word: 'chitarra', audio: 'audio/stimuli/chitarra.mp3'},
        {word: 'azzurro', audio: 'audio/stimuli/azzurro.mp3'},
        {word: 'bagno', audio: 'audio/stimuli/bagno.mp3'},
        {word: 'occhiali', audio: 'audio/stimuli/occhiali.mp3'},
        {word: 'cravatta', audio: 'audio/stimuli/cravatta.mp3'},
        {word: 'guanto', audio: 'audio/stimuli/guanto.mp3'},
        {word: 'campagna', audio: 'audio/stimuli/campagna.mp3'},
        {word: 'agricoltura', audio: 'audio/stimuli/agricoltura.mp3'},
        {word: 'montagna', audio: 'audio/stimuli/montagna.mp3'},
        {word: 'orizzonte', audio: 'audio/stimuli/orizzonte.mp3'},
        {word: 'ombra', audio: 'audio/stimuli/ombra.mp3'},
        {word: 'tasca', audio: 'audio/stimuli/tasca.mp3'},
        {word: 'pecora', audio: 'audio/stimuli/pecora.mp3'},
        {word: 'maglione', audio: 'audio/stimuli/maglione.mp3'},
        {word: 'valigia', audio: 'audio/stimuli/valigia.mp3'},
        {word: 'grano', audio: 'audio/stimuli/grano.mp3'},
        {word: 'rotella', audio: 'audio/stimuli/rotella.mp3'},
        {word: 'zaino', audio: 'audio/stimuli/zaino.mp3'},
        {word: 'elettrico', audio: 'audio/stimuli/elettrico.mp3'},
        {word: 'computer', audio: 'audio/stimuli/computer.mp3'},
        {word: 'irrigazione', audio: 'audio/stimuli/irrigazione.mp3'},
        {word: 'vasca', audio: 'audio/stimuli/vasca.mp3'},
        {word: 'fienile', audio: 'audio/stimuli/fienile.mp3'},
        {word: 'sedile', audio: 'audio/stimuli/sedile.mp3'},
        {word: 'nonno', audio: 'audio/stimuli/nonno.mp3'},
        {word: 'cioccolato', audio: 'audio/stimuli/cioccolato.mp3'},
        {word: 'corda', audio: 'audio/stimuli/corda.mp3'},
        {word: 'contadina', audio: 'audio/stimuli/contadina.mp3'},
    ]
    function presentStimuli(stimuli) {
        // Iterating over 4 pairs chunks in the stimuli array
        for (var i = 0; i < stimuli.length; i += 4) {
            // Separating the chunks
            var pairsChunk = stimuli.slice(i, i + 4);
            // Present the stimuli (the smallest items are the pairs of words)
            pairsChunk.forEach(stimulus => {
                timeline.push({
                    timeline: [
                        {
                            type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                            stimulus: stimulus.audio1,
                            choices: 'NO_KEYS',
                            trial_duration: 900
                        },
                        {
                            type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                            stimulus: stimulus.audio2,
                            choices: 'NO_KEYS',
                            trial_duration: 900,
                            post_trial_gap: 600
                        }
                    ],
                });
            });
            // After presenting each chunk of 4 pairs, ask the user to give an answer
            var response = {
                timeline: [
                    // Best/most similar pair response
                    {
                        type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                        stimulus: 'audio/sounds/separation_sound.mp3',
                        choices: "1, 2, 3, 4",
                        response_ends_trial: true,
                        post_trial_gap: 900

                    },
                    // Worst/most different pair response
                    {
                        type: jsPsychAudioKeyboardResponse,
                        stimulus: 'audio/sounds/separation_sound.mp3',
                        choices: "1, 2, 3, 4",
                        response_ends_trial: true,
                        post_trial_gap: 1000 // o più
                    },
                ]
            };
            timeline.push(response);
        }
    }


I think you have raised git as well
